# How to make (and save) custom warps in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So, I'm doing a picture in Photoshop, and I'm gonna need to use the warp tool to, well, warp layers. Many of them. And I need to be precise. So I'd like to be able to save the current warp, and be able to apply it next time. Or, alternatively, I'd like to be able to edit one of these few already saved warps that can be selected from the droplist.

Is it possible? It should be, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be, if possible, to record the warping process in Photoshop Actions and apply it to wherever it can be reused.

Comment: Liquify allows saving of meshes, too.